# LG Monitor Resolution 3440x1440 broken after Xubuntu-Update 18.04. -> 20.04

Tags: xubuntu, display-resolution, 20.04

I haven't been able to use my LG Monitor in the preferred ultrawide setting (3440x1440, 60) after updating to 20.04. Resolution 2560x1080 works, using a higher resolution creates a tiled/deferred desktop. (PC AMD Ryzen5, graphic Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series])

I tried HDMI and DisplayPort with the same result.

> ```
> xrandr shows:
> HDMI-A-0 connected 2560x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 800mm x 335mm
>   EDID: 
>       00ffffffffffff001e6df67658c90200
>       011e010380502278eaca95a6554ea126
>       0f50542108007140818081c0a9c0b300
>       d1c081000101e77c70a0d0a029503020
>       3a00204f3100001a9d6770a0d0a02250
>       30203a00204f3100001a000000fd0038
>       3d1e5a20000a202020202020000000fc
>       004c4720554c545241574944450a01ee
>       02031ef12309070749100403011f1359
>       5a128301000067030c00100038409f3d
>       70a0d0a0155030203a00204f3100001a
>       7e4800e0a0381f4040403a00204f3100
>       0018011d007251d01e206e285500204f
>       3100001e8c0ad08a20e02d10103e9600
>       204f31000018000000ff003030314e54
>       504335433631360a000000000000003f
> ...
> 3440x1440     59.97 +  49.99    29.99  
> ....
> ```

I tried to update drivers through adding PPA (http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu)

I tried to set different refresh-rates for resolution 3440x1440 with xrandr but always the same result.

Anyone with hints/ideas what I could do?
Thanks for help!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you found a solution?

Comment: Replying to my own comment. I just solved my problem. I have an Nvidia/Intel card and I just changed the "on-demande" mode to "performance" via the "nvidia-settings" app.